# Why does System::Convert have such strange defined behaviour for rounding?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm looking at the [MSDN documentation for System::Convert::ToUInt32(Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3569ft9(v=vs.110).aspx), and the return value is stated "value rounded to the nearest 32-bit unsigned integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6." This seems like a really odd way to round numbers, and actually seems to make the function unsuitable for most situations I would want to use it in. Any reason it should be this way?

Comment: This is related to C++, how? At best - it's the question about C++/CLI. Please [edit] your question with tags, that are, _actually_, related to your question.

Comment: Its called [Round-half-to-even or Bankers Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) btw, its intended to even distribution & break ties.

Comment: The processor really likes it, implemented as the FISTP instruction in x86 code.  That affected default choices for Math::Round() and Convert::ToInt32().  The 8087 coprocessor design had lots of quirks, but catering to the kind of people that wanted to pay (a lot) extra for the option probably had something to do with it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not seem to be related to C++ programming language (despite the tags), but about C#.

This is the [up-to-date official documentation for Convert.Uint32(double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3569ft9(v=vs.110).aspx), 
that implements what is commonly known as "round half to even" or "bankers rounding", see reference on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Rounding rules for floating point numbers (such as double) are described by the IEEE 754 standard ([wikipedia reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules)). Microsoft just followed those rules.

As an addition, the "bankers rounding" does not suffer from negative or positive bias as much as the "round half away from zero" method, at least over most reasonable distributions. Thus it is considered a "better" rounding method.

Comment: For some reason I linked to the wrong documentation page (fixed now), and I shouldn't have included the c++ tage, but rather the c++-cli tag which someone kindly corrected. Thanks for the info, but could you tell me why is this might be favoured over the standard rounding procedure people are generally taught in high school?

Comment: @tomd Edited my answer to add more info and an answer to your comment.